# I am trying to put my links on the right side of the screen using margin-left:auto, but its on the left side

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, nav

I am creating a navbar using flex CSS. My problem is that I wanted the links to be on the right side of the screen, but they are on the left side and next to the title which is what I do not want. I have tried margin-left: auto, but it does not work. Is there a different solution to this problem? The image down below:

[Image of Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kzVr.png)

[Solved] Adding `width: 100%;` to my nav class works, thank you Derek Bolger!

Here is the code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");

/*
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.name-title {
  font-family: "Montserrat Alternates", sans-serif;
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: #000;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  padding-right: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<!--Font Awesome CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<nav>
  <div class="name-title">Ayush Kumar</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you use `position:fixed` the container won't use the viewport's width (alike absolute) , add width:100% or set coordonates(answer below). -/-  You could also use: `position:sticky;top:0;`to keep it in the flow of the document/page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add width: 100%; to Nav

```
 nav {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or remove position fixed

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` is causing the issue. If you really want to use it, add some more details describing the position.

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

The above will give it a width of 100% since the position is 0 distance from both left and right end of the viewport. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/GRmRbRW)

Otherwise you can remove `position:fixed` too.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution to your Question, I hope I can help.

```
    <style>
            .main-nav {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
            .navbar {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                list-style: none;
            }
    
            .navbar li {
                padding-right: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <body>
            <nav class="main-nav">
    
                <h1>Name</h1>
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li>
                        link A
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        link B
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        link C
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Wrapping your nav tag in a body tag in your html. You set the body width to 100% but theres no body tag in your HTML.